# How to call servlet from JSF?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2

How to call servlet from JSF.If i want to call any servlet from page like index.xhtml then how can i do that? When user click on any link or button at that time i want to call servlet file instead of any bean file.

Answer (score 3):

Use a normal HTML `<form>` pointing to the URL of that servlet instead of a JSF `<h:form>`. Use normal HTML `<input>` elements instead of JSF `<h:inputXxx>` components.

```
<form action="servletURL" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" /> 
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

So, just the same plain 'ol HTML/Servlet way without any JSF form and input components in the view. It's not different in a Facelets page than in a normal HTML or legacy JSP page.

I however wonder if you aren't totally missing the point of JSF here. It might be worth the effort to re-ask the question in the form of how to achieve the particular functional requirement with JSF.